# Can FusionReactor stop/start ColdFusion instances?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, fusionreactor

We have several ColdFusion 2016 instances in production. We need the capability to remotely stop/start them as needed from a central dashboard. Can FusionReactor handle this? I wasn't able to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionReactor can execute a script in order to restart a service (such as CF 2016).  However, the trigger mechanism for FR doing this is based upon a monitored server (instance) changing state e.g. becoming non-responsive or going down.   In this case, FR would recognize this change of state and trigger a script.  This may or may not solve your problem - as you wrote that you would like to remotely start/stop the server as needed!  You can read about FR Enterprise Scripting here - http://docs.intergral.com/display/FR62/Using+FusionReactor+Enterprise+Scripting